# issue in join of laravel in controller

Tags: database, laravel, join

when i apply join server show me error
(2/2) QueryException
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use

my controller

```
$player_bet = DB::table('player_bet')
                ->join('poll', 'player_bet.poll_id = poll.id')
                ->join('poll_type', 'poll_type.id = poll.poll_type_id')
                ->join('tournament_week', 'poll.week_id = tournament_week.id')
                ->join('tournament', 'poll.tournament_id = tournament.id')
                ->join('users', 'player_bet.users_id = users.id')
                ->join('poll_winner', 'poll_winner.poll_id = poll.id AND poll_winner.user_id = users.id', 'left')
                ->where('users.id ='.$user_id)
                ->select('poll_winner.id AS winner_id, poll_winner.winning_amount AS won_amount,, poll_winner.tax_amount AS won_tax_amount, player_bet.id as bet_id, player_bet.create_time,poll.id poll_id,poll.winning_amount,poll.amount poll_amount,poll.week_id week_id,poll.description,poll.description_detail,poll_type.name poll_type,poll_type.id poll_type_id,tournament_week.week_no week_no, poll.is_close is_close, tournament.id tournament_id, tournament.name tournament_name,tournament.start_date,tournament.end_date,tournament.logo, users.username username')
                ->where('users_id',$user_id)
                ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your join syntax is incorrect: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#joins

Answer (score 0):

Also Your Where condition is Not proper

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem 1:

Change the multiple condition `join` method

```php
->join('poll_winner', 'poll_winner.poll_id = poll.id AND poll_winner.user_id = users.id', 'left')
```

to

```php
->leftjoin('poll_winner', function($join) {
  $join->on('poll_winner.poll_id', '=', 'poll.id')
       ->whereColumn('poll_winner.user_id', 'users.id');
})
```

#### Problem 2:

you have two `where` condition, the `where` need to be like this, the one is the column, the other be the column's value:

```php
->where('users.id', $user_id)
```

#### Problem 3:

If you want to use one string as parameter of select method, you need to use `selecRaw`

```php
->selectRaw('poll_winner.id AS winner_id, poll_winner.winning_amount AS won_amount,, poll_winner.tax_amount AS won_tax_amount, player_bet.id as bet_id, ...')
```

Or you need to use multiple strings as parameters of select method:

```php
->select('poll_winner.id AS winner_id', 'poll_winner.winning_amount AS won_amount', ...)
```